# Inserting values where some are new and some needs to be selected from a different table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a new row into a table. I have two of the values I want to insert already but I need to get the third from from another table.

```
function sendRequest($uuid, $friend) {
  $test = mysql_query("SELECT unique_id FROM Account WHERE name = '$friend'");
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO FriendList(player_id, friend_id, is_friends) VALUES('$uuid', '$test', 0)");
  if ($result) {
    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

So what I want is to use the result from test to get the value for friend_id.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_array($test, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$friend_id = $res[0]['unique_id'];
```

Verify $test and $res for correct results.